# I can't make edits to my files on GitHub web-based editor

Tags: git, github, editor, git-commit

The "Edit" button has disappeared on the web-based editor for GitHub.com

I used to be able to edit my files on GitHub directly online and commit my changes, but the edit button is now gone. Does it have something to do with the recent merging of the branches?

How can I get this edit button back? I can't post a picture because I don't have enough reputation yet, but it is the "EDIT" button that is usually to the left of the "RAW" "BLAME" "HISTORY" buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub gets updates from time to time.

You might want to checkout [Editing files in your repository · GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-files-in-your-repository), last updated on 26-Jul-14.

Actually, I can find the pencil edit button just next to "Raw", "Blame" and "History" when viewing files on github.com.

Comment: The "EDIT" button used to look the same as the "RAW" "BLAME" and "HISTORY", but it looks like they changed it to the pencil icon. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I have a repository with four files. The pencil icon shows up on the first two but not the last two. Any ideas what might be happening?